# How to get row with bigger index using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have two tables. I need to join it and if in the second table there is more than one row with the same `candidateId`, then I need to get only the last one (with `id = 153` in my example)

```
using (DbManager manager = new DbManager())
{
    var data = (from c in manager.Table1.AsNoTracking()
                join cm in manager.Table2.AsNoTracking()
                on c.CandidateId equals cm.CandidateId
                where cm.Id == manager.Table2.Last(z => z.CandidateId == cm.CandidateId).Id
                select new
                {
                    c,
                    cm.ManagerINN
                }).ToList();
}
```

My code return error:

*System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'StaffManagement.Models.DB.CandidateManager Last[CandidateManager](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[StaffManagement.Models.DB.CandidateManager], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[StaffManagement.Models.DB.CandidateManager,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'*

[image]

Comment: try to use [**group join**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join) and get the max id from grouped result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Entities (and SQL) does not [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) all LINQ methods!

replace

```
manager.Table2.Last(...).id
```

with

```
manager.Table2.OrderByDescending(...).FirstOrDefault()
```